# Could not find gem 'refinerycms-blog (~> 2.1.0) ruby'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, refinerycms

I have generated an application using `refinerycms myapp`,
and uncommented `gem 'refinerycms-blog', '~> 2.1.0'`
raises the following errror

```
Could not find gem 'refinerycms-blog (~> 2.1.0) ruby' in the gems available on this machine.
```

my gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.13'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end


# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'

# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# To use Jbuilder templates for JSON
# gem 'jbuilder'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
# gem 'debugger'

# Refinery CMS
gem 'refinerycms', '~> 2.1.0'

# Optionally, specify additional Refinery CMS Extensions here:
gem 'refinerycms-acts-as-indexed', '~> 1.0.0'
gem 'refinerycms-blog', '~> 2.1.0'
#  gem 'refinerycms-inquiries', '~> 2.1.0'
#  gem 'refinerycms-search', '~> 2.1.0'
#  gem 'refinerycms-page-images', '~> 2.1.0'
```

**UPDATE:**
Changed to the version 2.0.5 and raises the following

```
  Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "refinerycms-core":
  In Gemfile:
    refinerycms-blog (~> 2.0.5) ruby depends on
      refinerycms-core (~> 2.0.3) ruby

    refinerycms (~> 2.1.0) ruby depends on
      refinerycms-core (2.1.0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As kobaltz mentioned: The latest version of the refinerycms-blog is 2.0.5 (http://rubygems.org/gems/refinerycms-blog) and it requires refinerycms-core ~> 2.0.3 meaning that it won't work with version refinerycms 2.1

You can either downgrade whole refinerycms to 2.0.5 or use unreleased refinerycms-blog version directly from git repository: https://github.com/refinery/refinerycms-blog (version on master is 2.1). Just be aware that it might be unstable, as it hasn't been released.

Answer (score 1):

The latest version of the `refinerycms-blog` is `2.0.5`

`gem "refinerycms-blog", "~> 2.0.5"`

Comment: but why did the refinerycms generate 'refinerycms-blog' version '~> 2.1.0'

Comment: I think i dont need refinerycms-acts-as-indexed gem

Answer (score 0):

You can fork the blog repository and make changes accordingly . Until then you have to use 2.0.5 forcefully . Engine support for 2.1 will take some time to come as it has been recently released .I had to downgrade for the same reasons as i am using almost all engines of refinery .